# date should be format automatically according to time in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs

I have a date string like `"2022-05-19T14:44:18.887Z"`. I am creating a blog website in react so, I just want to show the time how old the post is. so i want to show the time like for example `2 min ago`, `2 hrs ago`, `10 hrs ago` , `1 day ago`, `5 days ago` then `6 days ago`. when As soon as the post becomes `7 days old` then it should show the month and year of that post like, `May 22`. It all the things should be automatically. For this i have used moment library. But i am unable to implement it. Please anyone can help me on this.

Comment: First show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this stuff

```
import moment from 'moment';

export const _convertTimeHumanReadable = (date) => {
  if (!date) return '';
  const segs = date.split(' ');
  if (segs.length > 1) {
      date = segs[0] + 'T' + segs[1];
  }
  const data = moment(date);
  const now = moment();
  let result = '';
  if (data.format('YYYY') !== now.format('YYYY')) {
      result = result + data.format('YYYY');
  }
  result = result + data.format('M/DD');
  return result;
};

export const convertTimeHumanReadable = (date) => {
  if (!date) return '';
  const now = moment();
  const data = moment(date);
  const duration = moment.duration(data.diff(now))
  if (duration.days() < -1) {
    return _convertTimeHumanReadable(date);
  }
  return duration.humanize(true);
}
```

This code humanize the date format up to 1 day ago
and if you can change `-1` to `-7` then humanize up to 7 days ago

```
  if (duration.days() < -1) {
```